# Admin Toolbar Save Button complete row is missing

Tags: acl

I Created a new user in editor and tried to access the site the complete toolbar is missing. I tried changing in global configuration or in modules but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you played with the ACL settings?

Comment: Yes..maybe there is database is corrupt views_tables trying to revert back the table.

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you restore the table exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved This by Restoring views_tables, it seems somehow the table went corrupt.